# Marionette LayoutView regions - Display non ItemView content

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm currently using `Marionette 2.4.7` and have my application structured using `LayoutViews`. Take the very simple example `LayoutViews` (normally the templates live separate):

```
var LayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "<div id="main-region"></div><div id="menu-region"></div>",
    regions: {
        mainRegion: "#main-region",
        menuRegion: "#menu-region"
    }
});

var MainLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: "<div id="title-region"></div><div id="content-region"></div>",
    regions: {
        titleRegion: "#title-region",
        contentRegion: "#content-region"
    }
});
```

Basically the page is split into two sections, a section to display page title and a section to display the main content. I populate the content region using the following:

```
    var layoutView = new LayoutView();

    var mainLayoutView = new MainLayoutView({ className: "someClass" });
    layoutView.mainRegion.show(mainLayoutView);
    var contentLayoutView = new ContentLayoutView();
    mainLayoutView.contentRegion.show(contentLayoutView);
```

The `ContentLayoutView` has sub-regions and does quite a lot of other stuff, so is quite a complex view. The `titleRegion` of the `MainLayoutView` only displays a few words, so very simple.

Now to my question, is there a way I can get around the need to create an `ItemView` for the `titleRegion`, just to display a few words? This scenario is repeated a few times throughout my application and it seems overkill needing to create separate `ItemViews` for each case. I know I can set the `DIV HTML` using:

```
$("#title-region").html("Page title");
```

but I want to stick to the `Marionette` way of doing things.

I have tried:

```
mainLayoutView.titleRegion.show("Page name");
```

but I get the error: `'view.on' is not a function`, obviously because the `.show` is expecting an `ItemView/LayoutView`.

Comment: Is your `mainLayoutView` re-rendered when you need the title to change or do you need the title to change when you change the view in `contentRegion`?

Comment: @rdubya The `mainLayoutView` is re-rendered as the user scrolls through a menu, with the `titleRegion` and `contentRegion` being set each time

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the code that does the re-render? If you can't, that's ok. It would just be a little easier to give you some sample code if I could see it.

Comment: @rdubya I've just updated the question to show there is an extra `LayoutView` that `MainLayoutView` lives in. There is also a `MenuLayoutView`. Basically when the menu item changes, `layoutView.mainRegion.empty();` is called, then the `MainLayoutView` is created again as above. I guess this is not so much a re-render, as a destroy and create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably include the title as part of the mainLayoutView's template. I'm not sure what templating language you are using but it might look something like:

`"<div id="title-region">{title}</div><div id="content-region"></div>"`

Then you can define a `templateHelpers` function in your `MainLayoutView` definition like:

```
templateHelpers: function() {
  return { title: this.options.title };
}
```

When you create your `MainLayoutView` you would then pass in whatever title you need:

```
var layoutView = new LayoutView();
var mainLayoutView = new MainLayoutView({
                                           className: "someClass",
                                           title: "Welcome!"
                                        });
layoutView.mainRegion.show(mainLayoutView);
var contentLayoutView = new ContentLayoutView();
mainLayoutView.contentRegion.show(contentLayoutView);
```

`title` may actually already be a property on the view (I can't remember), so you may need to use `layoutTitle` or something like that in the places that I used `title`

Comment: Very nice solution :) Cheers.

Comment: I have now struck the problem where the `contentRegion` contains a menu that needs to update the `titleRegion` as the user navigates..